# Python built-in function conflicts with spark

Tags: apache-spark, conflict, built-in

I am using Databricks and I am trying to write a python function and then convert it to udf. In my python function's output, I am trying to round the result to 8 decimal places, and it worked yesterday.

However, when I re-ran the code today, the error like below shows up. It looks like Databrick notebook recognized the python built-in 'round' function as a RDD method? And it is asking for a column or string input.

[image]

When I changed it to string input, it returns a Column...but I simply want a number.

[image]

Is there a way that I can tell the engine to use python built-in function instead? I try 'from collections import round as py_round' but it doesn't work.

Many thanks in advance!

Comment: python or pyspark? See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47046827/trouble-with-pyspark-round-function

Comment: Thank you! It looks like I used from pyspark.sql.functions import *, which include a function named round, that replaced the python built-in function.