# Transforming pyspark data frame column with round function not working (pyspark)

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark, apache-spark-sql, rounding

I want to create a new column of a spark data frame with rounded values of an already existing column. The "em" column is of type float.

I already checked various posts, but couldn't figure it out. Including the following link:[Trouble With Pyspark Round Function](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47046827/trouble-with-pyspark-round-function)

Here is my code:

```
import pyspark.sql.functions as f
df = df.withColumn("rounded", f.round(f.col("em"), 3))
df.show()
```

The newly generated column "rounded" is exactly the same as the original column "em". I'm working with pyspark version 2.3.0 in Zeppelin Notebook on a Cloudera Cluster.

UPDATE:

Tried the following:

```
%pyspark
s2_em = s2.select('em')
print "Datatype:", type(s2_em)
s2_em.printSchema()
s2_em = s2_em.withColumn('rounded', f.round(f.col('em'), 3))
s2_em = s2_em.withColumn('plus', f.col('em') + f.col('rounded'))
s2_em = s2_em.withColumn('minus', f.col('em') - f.col('rounded'))
s2_em = s2_em.withColumn('multiplication', f.col('em') * f.col('rounded'))
s2_em.limit(5).show()
```

This yields the following, but the rounding still doesn't work. Any other hints?:

```
Datatype: <class 'pyspark.sql.dataframe.DataFrame'>
root |-- em: float (nullable = true)
+------------+------------+------------+-----+--------------+
|          em|     rounded|        plus|minus|multiplication|
+------------+------------+------------+-----+--------------+
|1.14209626E9|1.14209626E9|2.28419251E9| 0.0|   1.3043839E18|
|1.25046528E9|1.25046528E9|2.50093056E9| 0.0|  1.56366345E18|
| 9.5720672E8| 9.5720672E8|1.91441344E9| 0.0|   9.1624469E17|
| 1.1392649E9| 1.1392649E9|2.27852979E9| 0.0|  1.29792455E18|
|1.29539699E9|1.29539699E9|2.59079398E9| 0.0|  1.67805334E18|
+------------+------------+------------+-----+--------------+
```

Comment: The show in ```df = df.withColumn("rounded", f.round(f.col("em"), 3)).show()``` is incorrect, you have to remove it

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Did a test with same code and it runs perfectly, see the example below:

```py
import pyspark.sql.functions as f
from pyspark import Row
from pyspark.shell import spark

df = spark.createDataFrame([
    Row(em=3.45631),
    Row(em=2.82945),
    Row(em=7.76261),
    Row(em=2.76790)
])

df = df.withColumn('rounded', f.round(f.col('em'), 3))
df.show()
```

Output:

```
+-------+-------+                                                               
|     em|rounded|
+-------+-------+
|3.45631|  3.456|
|2.82945|  2.829|
|7.76261|  7.763|
| 2.7679|  2.768|
+-------+-------+
```

**UPDATE**

In fact, its floating values ​​contain the exponent `E9` and`E8`. For example, the value `1.14209626E9` is equal to `1142096260`.

To round them, it is necessary to divide the value by `1e9` and then call `round` function.

See the example below:

```py
import pyspark.sql.functions as f
from pyspark import Row
from pyspark.shell import spark

df = spark.createDataFrame([
    Row(em=1.14209626E9),
    Row(em=1.25046528E9),
    Row(em=9.5720672E8)
])

df = df.withColumn('rounded', (f.round(f.col('em') / 1e9, 3)) * 1e9)
df.show()
```

Output:

```
+------------+-------+
|          em|rounded|
+------------+-------+
|1.14209626E9|1.142E9|
|1.25046528E9| 1.25E9|
| 9.5720672E8| 9.57E8|
+------------+-------+
```

Comment: Hi @Kafels, thank you for the example, if i run your code, it works quite well. BUT:if i try to run this for my own dataframe, it is still not working. I'm working on Zeppelin Notebook. Maybe there is something wrong with my dataframe, the column 'em' just won't get rounded. I just tried to create another column with + and that worked. Is it using the pyspark Implementation of the round() function?