# data frame: How to round the values in some columns in Databricks Pyspark

Tags: python, sql, dataframe, pyspark, databricks

Pyspark python in databricks

I have the following dataframe already created in Databricks.
The values in some columns should be rounded to integer only, which means 4.5 round to  5, 2.3 round to 2

df1:

| Name | Number | Location | Quantity | UoM |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| A | 1.236 | USA | 10.558 | PC |
| B | 2.8988 | France | 58.12999 | PC |

the values in Number and Quantity columns need to be rounded. the other columns should be kept the same.

I expect the df1 could be changed to like below

| Name | Number | Location | Quantity | UoM |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| A | 1 | USA | 11 | PC |
| B | 3 | France | 58 | PC |

BTW: 2.5 should be rounded to 3, not 2

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the [round](https://spark.apache.org/docs/3.1.1/api/python/reference/api/pyspark.sql.functions.round.html) function to achieve the desired solution.

```
from pyspark.sql.functions import round

df = spark.createDataFrame(
        [["A", 1.236, "USA", 9.5, "PC"], ["B", 2.8988, "France",58.12999, "PC"]],
        ["Name", "Number", "Location", "Quantity", "UoM"])

df.withColumn("Number", round("Number")).withColumn("Quantity", round("Quantity")).show()
```

This outputs the columns in floating points but you can cast it to integer if required.

```
+----+------+--------+--------+---+
|Name|Number|Location|Quantity|UoM|
+----+------+--------+--------+---+
|   A|   1.0|     USA|    11.0| PC|
|   B|   3.0|  France|    58.0| PC|
+----+------+--------+--------+---+
```

Answer (score 0):

Assuming based on DataBricks documentation that you are referring to a pandas DataFrame, you can use apply on the dataframe.

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame([[1.1, "a", 2.22222222222], [1.5, "b", 5.5555555555], [1.7, "c", 6.666666]], columns=["0", "1", "2"])
print(temp)

"""
     0  1         2
0  1.1  a  2.222222
1  1.5  b  5.555556
2  1.7  c  6.666666
"""

df[["0", "2"]] = df[["0", "2"]].apply(round).astype("int32")
print(temp)

"""
   0  1  2
0  1  a  2
1  2  b  6
2  2  c  7
"""
```

On top of using `.apply` on the specific columns that you want to change, you would notice that I also call `.astype` on the results. This is because even though `round` would return an integer since no `ndigits` is supplied, the DataFrame has those columns registered as a float and would have the values casted as a float. Converting it with `.astype("int32")` would turn them back into integer values. You could change the type depending on need as well, such as `int64` for very large values.

Comment: pandas seems doesn't work. We're using pyspark in databricks dataframe

Comment: What about the pandas spark API `pyspark.pandas`? If not, look into the round function in pyspark. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47046827/trouble-with-pyspark-round-function

Comment: It works. I added like this way, but 9.5 was rounded as 9, we need 9.5 rounded to 10 func.round(col('Number'), 0)

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure why previous post talked about Pandas.

For pyspark, you can create a custom function and then use it :

```
def custom_round(column):
    return F.when(F.col(column) - F.floor(F.col(column)) >= 0.5, F.ceil(F.col(column))).otherwise(F.floor(F.col(column)))

df = df.withColumn("RoundedQuantity", custom_round_udf(F.col("Quantity")))
```